# Simpicial resolution in Cotangent Complex

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I am reading Cotangent complex from Loday's book Cyclic Homology. My doubt is related to the simplicial resolution of $k$- algebra $A$ which is used in the definition of cotangent complex.. Let me first define notations and definition:

Let $A$ be commutative unital $k$-algebra, where $k$ is commutative ring with 1 and $k[i] = k[x_{1},...,x_{i}]$ denote the polynomial $k$-algebra in $i$ variables.  Let $P(A)$ denote the category whose objects are ($k[i], \alpha)$, where $\alpha : k[i] \rightarrow A$ is $k$-algebra homomorphism and morphism from ($k[i], \alpha)$ to ($k[i'], \alpha')$ is a $k$-algebra map $f : k[i] \rightarrow k[i']$ such that $\alpha' o f$= $\alpha$. Let $Alg$ denote the category of $k$-algebra. Let $U : P(A) \rightarrow Alg$ be the forgetful functor defined as  $U(k[i], \alpha) = k[i]$ . Let $\mathcal{C}_{U}$ be the category associated to $U$ as follows: Obj($\mathcal{C}_{U}$) = ( $\alpha$, $x$) , where $\alpha : k[i] \rightarrow A$ is an object of $P(A)$ and $x$ is an element of $U(k[i], \alpha) = k[i]$ and a morphism ( $\alpha$, $x$) to ( $\alpha'$, $x'$) in $\mathcal{C}_{U}$ is simply a morphism $f$ in $P(A)$ such that $f(x) = x'$. Let $P_{\ast}$ be the algebra generated by the nerve of the category $\mathcal{C}_{U}$. Explicitly, its $n$-th term $P_{n}$ described as follows: $P_{n} = \otimes_{(f_{0},f_{1},...,f_{n})} k[i_{0}]$, where the tensor product is over all strings of maps:
  $k[i_{0}] \rightarrow k[i_{1}] \rightarrow$ ... $k[i_{n}] \rightarrow A$ and $f_{i}$ are the map originating from $k[i]$. In fact $P_{\ast}$ is simplical $k$-algebra since $i$-the face map maps the generator corresponding ${(f_{0},f_{1},.,f_{i-1},f_{i}..,f_{n})}$ to generator corresponding to the map ${(f_{0},f_{1},.f_{i}f_{i-1}..,f_{n})}$ and $i$-th degeneracy map just insert identity map at the $i$-th place. So $P_{\ast}$ is indeed a complex associated simplicial algebra and indeed it is augmented $A$-complex given by sending the generator ${(f_{0},f_{1},.,f_{i-1},f_{i}..,f_{n})}$ to $f_{n}..f_{i}f_{i-1}..f_{0}$.

My first question is that why $P_{\ast}$ is a resolution? And second question is that, here there does not seem to be any choice of resolution so what is the meaning of any two resolution are homotopy equivalent ?